# Azure AD Multi-tenant Applications - How to implement Token Validation?

Tags: azure, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have a multi tenant *Web app / API* registered in Azure ad and that connected to an API App. The API App has Active Directory Authentication setup. At the moment only one other tenant needs access to api.  I made sure only they can get access by putting `https://sts.windows.net/<third party tenant>/` in the *Issuer URL*. My question is: How would I go about giving a second (or more) tenants access to the api? I can't add anymore tenant ids in the *Issuer URL* so I'm kinda at a loss

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach you are using currently will work only in a single tenant scenario, i.e. Automatic validation of tenant by setting IssuerURL works only in a single tenant scenario.

In case of multi-tenant applications, the application is responsible for storing and validating all possible issuers. This is **by design** and exact guidance on this topic from Microsoft is available here:

[Work with claims-based identities in Azure AD: Issuer Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/claims#issuer-validation)

> For a single-tenant application, you can just check that the issuer is
>   your own tenant. In fact, the OIDC middleware does this automatically
>   by default. In a multi-tenant app, you need to allow for multiple
>   issuers, corresponding to the different tenants. Here is a general
>   approach to use:
>
> - In the OIDC middleware options, set ValidateIssuer to false. This    turns off the automatic check.
> - When a tenant signs up, store the    tenant and the issuer in your user DB.
> - Whenever a user signs in, look    up the issuer in the database.If the issuer isn't found, it means    that tenant hasn't signed up. You
>     can redirect them to a sign up    page.
> - You could also blacklist certain tenants; for example, for    customers that didn't pay their subscription.

So, in case of a .NET based web application the code in your startup class would change to something like this.. notice the **new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateIssuer = false }**

[Authenticate using Azure AD and OpenID Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/authenticate#configure-the-auth-middleware)

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions {
    ClientId = configOptions.AzureAd.ClientId,
    ClientSecret = configOptions.AzureAd.ClientSecret, // for code flow
    Authority = Constants.AuthEndpointPrefix,
    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = configOptions.AzureAd.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
    SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateIssuer = false },
    Events = new SurveyAuthenticationEvents(configOptions.AzureAd, loggerFactory),
});
```

Once you have disabled the Validate issuer, you will need to handle the validation yourself. Here is a sample with some guidance around how to do this validation yourself

[Update your code to handle multiple issuer values](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview.md#update-your-code-to-handle-multiple-issuer-values)

You will at least need to check the "tid" claim which captures the Azure AD Tenant Id against your own list of valid tenant IDs, before you let the call go through.

> When a single tenant application validates a token, it checks the
>   signature of the token against the signing keys from the metadata
>   document, and makes sure the issuer value in the token matches the one
>   that was found in the metadata document.
>
> Since the /common endpoint doesn’t correspond to a tenant and isn’t an
>   issuer, when you examine the issuer value in the metadata for /common
>   it has a templated URL instead of an actual value:
>
> https://sts.windows.net/{tenantid}/
>
> Therefore, a multi-tenant application can’t validate tokens just by
>   matching the issuer value in the metadata with the issuer value in the
>   token. A multi-tenant application needs logic to decide which issuer
>   values are valid and which are not, based on the tenant ID portion of
>   the issuer value.
>
> For example, if a multi-tenant application only allows sign in from
>   specific tenants who have signed up for their service, then it must
>   check either the issuer value or the tid claim value in the token to
>   make sure that tenant is in their list of subscribers. If a
>   multi-tenant application only deals with individuals and doesn’t make
>   any access decisions based on tenants, then it can ignore the issuer
>   value altogether.

**(EDIT) More information on Validating Tokens** 
I'm trying to answer your questions from comments here.

1. Here is sample code which does the task of manually validating JWT tokens.
   [Manually validating a JWT access token in a web API](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation#manually-validating-a-jwt-access-token-in-a-web-api)

[image]

A useful excerpt..

> Validating the claims When an application receives an access token
>   upon user sign-in, it should also perform a few checks against the
>   claims in the access token. These verifications include but are not
>   limited to:
>
> audience claim, to verify that the ID token was intended to be given
>   to your application not before and "expiration time" claims, to verify
>   that the ID token has not expired issuer claim, to verify that the
>   token was issued to your app by the v2.0 endpoint nonce, as a token
>   replay attack mitigation You are advised to use standard library
>   methods like JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken Method
>   (JwtSecurityToken) to do most of the aforementioned heavy lifting. You
>   can further extend the validation process by making decisions based on
>   claims received in the token. For example, multi-tenant applications
>   can extend the standard validation by inspecting value of the tid
>   claim (Tenant ID) against a set of pre-selected tenants to ensure they
>   only honor token from tenants of their choice.

2. Sample Access Token, just for understanding: Access Token and Id_token are both simple base64 encoded JSON Web Tokens (JWT). You can decode these to find the claims and then validate them. I'm sharing a sample which has code to do just that. Before that here is a sample access token from one of Microsoft Docs. I just took one for example from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#successful-response-1)

Actual Value: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1N... (a long encoded string continues)
Decoded Value (you can check this easily using a website like https://jwt.io):

```
{
  "aud": "https://service.contoso.com/",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/7fe81447-da57-4385-becb-6de57f21477e/",
  "iat": 1388440863,
  "nbf": 1388440863,
  "exp": 1388444763,
  "ver": "1.0",
  "tid": "7fe81447-da57-4385-becb-6de57f21477e",
  "oid": "68389ae2-62fa-4b18-91fe-53dd109d74f5",
  "upn": "frankm@contoso.com",
  "unique_name": "frankm@contoso.com",
  "sub": "deNqIj9IOE9PWJWbHsftXt2EabPVl0Cj8QAmefRLV98",
  "family_name": "Miller",
  "given_name": "Frank",
  "appid": "2d4d11a2-f814-46a7-890a-274a72a7309e",
  "appidacr": "0",
  "scp": "user_impersonation",
  "acr": "1"
}
```

As you can see the decoded value has many claims including "tid" which you're about to validate.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I should've clarified that I'm authenticating from a native app. Can I retain signin using the `common` endpoint, or do I need to change the whole signin procedure. I currently show a webview with the `common`  endpoint where the user can sign in

Comment: Yes you should be able to retain common endpoint. The whole point of validating issuer/tid yourself is because common endpoint doesn’t belong to any single tenant. Read through the link at the end of my answer about how to handle multiple issuers

Comment: I'm sorry, but I stil don't understand how that gets me a tenantid I can check against a 'whitelist'. How do I `check either the issuer value or the tid claim value in the token`. - Thanks for you patience and help

Comment: Whenever you get a token from AzureAD (even from the common endpoint), the token will contain a tid claim which tells what tenant in Azure AD does the currently logged in user belongs to. In your code you compare that value against a whitelist (all your valid Azure AD Tenant Ids.. you can build this whitelist at the time of tenant sign up)

Comment: I only get an `access_token` back from in the auth url. I currently only have `token` as value in `response_type` in the auth url

Comment: It's tough to answer in comments, so I've edited my answer.. please take a look

Comment: I didn't even know that was possible. Thank you.