# Validate token header received by web api

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, owin, power-automate

My scenario is I have this web app which is authenticating against an azure ad via OWIN and I have created web api that is called by the HTTP Action via the Microsoft Flow.

Now in the flow, I have setup the HTTP call with Azure AD OAuth, and it was successfully generating Authorization token headers and it calls the web api.

At first I put the [Authorize] attribute like I normally do, as this forces the sign in if the request is not authenticated, but in this case whenever I use it, the api is not being called and the request is being denied even if it has the token headers.

Now as a work around I thought, instead of using the [Authorized] attribute, maybe I can just validate the token of the request. But I'm not sure how to do it. I'm pretty sure just checking if the token is in the header will not suffice, i don't think it's secure either. I've googled and read some post but seems to be pointing using JWT.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> At first I put the [Authorize] attribute like I normally do, as this
>   forces the sign in if the request is not authenticated, but in this
>   case whenever I use it, the api is not being called and the request is
>   being denied even if it has the token headers.
>
> Now as a work around I thought, instead of using the [Authorized]
>   attribute,

**Avoid workarounds with Authentication/Authorization**

My suggestion would be to not look for workarounds as you could end up compromising on security. The behavior you mention here could be due to:

1. Incorrect configuration/code related to Authentication in your web API or if everything is good with web API there could be something wrong with the token being sent to it.

   Here is a [code sample from Microsoft Docs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop#integrating-azure-ad-into-a-windows-desktop-application-using-interactive-authentication), which is very similar to your situation and it uses **[Authorize] attribute** in Web API code for all secure routes (for e.g. /TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs). Try to compare your web API configs/code against this one step by step.

   This sample shows a Web API getting called by a WPF desktop application (in your case Microsoft Flow will be calling the API).
2. If everything is correct for Web API, there could be something wrong with the token being sent to it. Like a common issue is wrong Audience (it should be the App ID URI for your Web API).

   In this case, you can inspect the token being sent using a tool like https://jwt.ms or https://jwt.io to check all claims and then decide.

**Token Validation**

Token validation is to make sure token was issued by right or trusted authority/issuer, is still valid (not expired) and for right tenant etc. It's required along with normal authentication and authorization, and does not replace the need for [Authorize] attribute for all secure routes.

You don't mention if you Web API is meant to be used by multiple tenants or is it a single tenant application.

In case it's a single tenant application then most of the validation part is covered by Authentication configuration itself. Again refer to the sample code shown above (specifically /TodoListService/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs)

In case it's multi-tenant application then there is a little more work involved at your end. I have answered in detail around that in this SO Post ([Azure AD Multi-tenant Applications - How to implement Token Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347821/azure-ad-multi-tenant-applications-how-to-implement-token-validation/52350228#52350228)). Venture into this only if it's applicable for your Web API's case.